# How to download proper polygons from osm-boundaries?

Tags: openstreetmap, boundaries

I am trying to get proper country polygons from OSM, and where ever I look everyone is pointing towards osm-boundaries.
Well, I would like to get Norway and Sweden, but selecting

- the administrative level 2 of Norway,
- OSM database = Latest,
- name field = name:en, name,
- water/land = Land

only gives me all sorts of islands. The continental part of Norway is not included.
The same goes for Sweden.

Here the example for the county of Skåne in Sweden. With the water setting you get one single polygon, but no sharp coast lines.

[image]

With the land setting you get? Islands of the county, but nothing from the other parts of the county.

[image]

Can somebody explain how I can get the entire area, without the sea water buffer for the countries?